# Check for unique values in a list, and then increment the duplicates c# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a situation where I want to enumerate over a list of strings, and then check for duplicates and increment the number at the end if there are any duplicates present.  The order of the strings is irrelevant.

E.g if my list is:

> - Test
> - Tester
> - Tester
> - Tester

It would be changed to

> - Test
> - Tester
> - Tester (1)
> - Tester (2)

Is there an easy way to do this? My current thoughts are to do a group by, and then find the count of each group and then recursively go over each group and change the values - but sure there is a quicker way to do this using LINQ

Comment: Clearly strings are being used here.

Comment: The list can be in any order and any index of the duplicate needs to have the index of the duplicate added as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Select` that projects the index:

```
List<string> resultList = list
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .SelectMany(g => g
      .Select((s, index) => $"{s}{(index == 0 ? "" : $" ({index})")}"))
    .ToList();
```

---

Update: If you want to maintain the original order as commented, so not group duplicates together but `A,B,A => A,B,A1`, then you can use this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dupcounter = new();
List<string> resultList = new(list.Count);
foreach(string s in list)
{
    dupcounter.TryGetValue(s, out int n);
    dupcounter[s] = ++n;
    resultList.Add(n > 1 ? $"{s} ({n-1})" : s);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7XQTb

Comment: ahead of me for a couple of seconds:) can I advise string interpolation: `.Select((s, i) => i == 0 ? s : $"{s} ({i})")`?

Comment: Brilliant - this is exactly what I am after - thank you so much!

Comment: This doesnt maintain the original order if the dupes are scattered throughout the list i think

Comment: @user433342: if the list is really a list (so an in memory collection and not a Linq-To-Entities query), `GroupBy` and `Select` have a stable sort. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__): _"The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey,TElement>. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source."_

Comment: I meant it won’t do A,B,A=>A,B,A2

Comment: @user433342: i get it, no, it will group duplicates together, so the result is: `A, A1, B`

Comment: @user433342: edited my answer to provide a way to maintain the original order